# In Matlab, How to change axes color?

Tags: matlab, plot, colors, axes

Someone, please tell me how to change the color of axes. When I run the below code, I get the time and the amplitude values on axes in black color, which is the default. I want to change its color. I have managed to change the color of the labels.

```
dt = 0:0.2:50;
y = 2*pi*sin(dt);
subplot(211)
plot(dt,y,'r');
grid on
xlabel('Time','color','r')
ylabel('Amplitude','color','r')
z=pi*cos(dt);
subplot(212)
plot(dt,z,'g')
grid on
xlabel('Time','color','g')
ylabel('Amplitude','color','g')
```

Comment: Have you read [Axes Properties](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for [`subplot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html) you'll see a syntax that allows you to store the handle to your `Axes` object to a variable, which you can use to specify [Axes properties](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html):

> ax = subplot(___) returns the Axes object created. Use `ax` to make future modifications to the axes. For a list of properties, see [Axes Properties](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html).

Because [`plot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) (with [`hold off`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html)) resets the axes properties, you'll want to [`set`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/set.html) the `'XColor'` and `'YColor'` after you have made your plots.

For example:

```
dt = 0:0.2:50;
y = 2*pi*sin(dt);
ax(1) = subplot(211);
plot(dt,y,'r');
grid on
xlabel('Time','color','r')
ylabel('Amplitude','color','r')
z=pi*cos(dt);
ax(2) = subplot(212);
plot(dt,z,'g')
grid on
xlabel('Time','color','g')
ylabel('Amplitude','color','g')

set(ax, {'XColor', 'YColor'}, {'r', 'r'; 'g', 'g'});
```

Gives us the following:

[image: yay]

Comment: By these words: *"I get the time and the amplitude values on axes in black color, which is the default. I want to change its color"*. I thought the OP wanted this: `set(gca,'XColor','g','YColor','g');`

Comment: @SardarUsama oops